# Vectorizing a function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a function that I am trying to vectorize:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'state': ['a', 'b', 'c']*200,
    'read': [random.uniform(10,50) for i in range(600)],
    'write': [random.uniform(0,10) for i in range(600)],
    'cansu': [random.uniform(11,20) for i in range(600)],
    'brink': [random.uniform(2,10) for i in range(600)]
})


loop = pd.DataFrame({
    'state': ['a','a','c','b','c'],
    'x': [1,2,3,2,4],
    'y': [2,3,4,4,1]
})

def regress(z,x,y):
    X = data.query("state==@z").iloc[:,x].values
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    Y = data.query("state==@z").iloc[:,y].values
    result = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
    return result.params[1]
```

I know I can use `apply, list comprehensions, itertools, map, filter, reduce, np.vectorize, etc.` and all the cool functions. However, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
loop['slope'] = regress(loop['state'].values, loop['x'].values, loop['y'].values)
```

which is not working at the moment. Is this possible? If yes, how do I rewrite or modify my function to make this possible?

Comment: I can't off hand tell what you are trying to do, and don't see what's supposed to be "vectorized".  I'm looking for an iteration or dataframe `apply`.  `loop` is a DataFrame`, not a `for loop`.  "vectorize" in `numpy` usually means replacing a python level iteration with one or more calls to compiled numpy methods.  It moves the iteration from Python to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in this way

same as your code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'state': ['a', 'b', 'c']*200,
    'read': [random.uniform(10,50) for i in range(600)],
    'write': [random.uniform(0,10) for i in range(600)],
    'cansu': [random.uniform(11,20) for i in range(600)],
    'brink': [random.uniform(2,10) for i in range(600)]
})


loop = pd.DataFrame({
    'state': ['a','a','c','b','c'],
    'x': [1,2,3,2,4],
    'y': [2,3,4,4,1]
})

def regress(z,x,y):
    X = data.query("state==@z").iloc[:,x].values
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    Y = data.query("state==@z").iloc[:,y].values
    result = sm.OLS(Y,X).fit()
    return result.params[1]
```

execution in lists:

```
loop['slope'] = regress(list(loop['state'].values), list(loop['x'].values), list(loop['y'].values))
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know this was possible. Are there any speed gains in using this over the others?

Comment: Me too, I learned a new thing... It would be nice to compare it with the others in term of time performances